# "color" command works on cmd.exe but not in PHP CLI. Can it be done?

Tags: php, windows

If you open cmd.exe and type "color 70" and press Enter, the entire terminal changes color theme to grey-white background with black text instead of the normal black background with white text. Cool. When I try the same thing in PHP, nothing happens.

```
shell_exec('color 70');
```

Note that I know about those "ANSI codes", and I already use them to change the color of text and the background of a *paragraph*. However, this doesn't change the entire background color of the terminal, the way that "color 70" does. Those ANSI background color codes only changes the background of the specific text you output, leaving all the other areas intact. There is a major difference.

How come the "color" command won't work in PHP CLI? Is there some other way I can change the PHP CLI terminal windows' background colours?

Comment: It's only changing the color for the child process that the shell_exec is calling not the parent.

Comment: That's odd. How come that command behaves so differently?

Comment: PD of [How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line](//stackoverflow.com/q/2048509) / [Colorizing Windows command line output from PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/7086034)

Comment: cmd.exe is a shell .That starts your pp program. That then starts a new shell cmd.exe that runs color. You could just write a batch file to put you commands in. Do a search for windows batch file.

Comment: @JasonK What is a "pp" program? And what do you mean by "just write a batch file"? I'm using and asking about PHP CLI -- not .bat files. (Which I do use to start the PHP scripts, BTW.)

Comment: Apparently this `shell_exec` function creates a new console instead of inheriting the current console. For comparison, try `os.system('color 70')` in Python, which does not create a new console.

Comment: Is there a shell_exec which doesn't behave like that? I mean, there are like 10 different functions in PHP to run terminal commands.

Comment: I guess try all 10. ;-) I don't use PHP.

Comment: I actually just tried all the ones I know about. None of them changed the terminal background colour, as expected.

Comment: All I can tell you is at a lower level in the Windows API, a new console is created if the `CreateProcess` call includes either the creation flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` or the creation flag `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` (i.e. a new console that creates no window, which is more extreme than creating a new console with a hidden window via `STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow`), and the process is created without a console at all if the call includes the creation flag `DETACHED_PROCESS`.